# Perl open layer to turn off CRLF translation?

Tags: perl, unix, batch-file

I'm trying to parse an input file only having Unix `LF` to an output file. In between is some non relevant regex replacement for this question.
As perl automatically adds `CR` linefeeds, which I do not want, I tried disabling it with:

`perl -Mopen=IO,:raw -pe "SomeRegexReplacement" %INPUT% >%OUTPUT%`

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html:

> If LAYER is omitted or specified as **:raw** the filehandle is made
>   suitable for passing binary data. This includes **turning off possible
>   CRLF translation** and marking it as bytes (as opposed to Unicode
>   characters).

BUT: the resulting file still contains `CRLF` linefeeds.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't apply :raw to STDOUT. Change

```
-Mopen=IO,:raw
```

to

```
-Mopen=:std,IO,:raw
```

Comment: I used `IO` as perl is giving me an error otherwise:`Unknown PerlIO layer class 'std' (need IN, OUT or IO) at -e line 0.`

Comment: then you left off the `:`

Comment: With both colons, I get the same error message. as @membersound.  I get this even if I simply run `perl -Mopen=:std,:raw` by itself.

Comment: due to a bug (https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/18470) a working option would need to be `-Mopen=':std,IO,:raw(0)'`